# Proving transitivity for a particular relation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let us state that $\frac{a}{b}\equiv \frac{c}{d}$ iff $ad=bc$, where $a,b,c,d\in R$. Here, $R$ is a ring, not necessarily commutative, and $b$ and $d$ are regular elements (hence not zero-divisors).

I have to prove that the relation $\equiv$ is transitive. But I'm having trouble proving it. How do I prove that $$af=be$$ given the conditions $ad=bc$ and $cf=de$? I do not have commutativity. All I have as of now is $adf=bcf(=bde$ as $cf=de$), without knowing how to cancel $d$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in your definition. Assume momentarily that $b$ and $d$ are invertible. Then $ad=bc$ means that $b^{-1}a=cd^{-1}$. In other words, the fraction $\frac ab$ in your definition generalizes the left division by $b$, and the fraction $\frac cd$ generalizes the right division by $d$. This is not good, and this is why your attempt to prove transitivity fails. In fact, you definition is even not symmetric. Do not mix left and right division in the same notation.